# How to safely edit QTextDocument within Qml TextEdit component

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm working on a collaborative text editor using QML and I have experimented with the underlying mechanism within Qt C++ and it works. However, when trying to implement things in QML, I seem to have run into an issue: The `QTextDocument` stored within a QML TextEdit component is not to be touched. As written in the documentation:

> Warning: The QTextDocument provided is used internally by Qt Quick elements to provide text manipulation primitives. You are not allowed to perform any modification of the internal state of the QTextDocument. If you do, the element in question may stop functioning or crash.

The process I ended up with was using a `QTextCursor` to edit the `QTextDocument` and I have tested it by extracting the `QTextDocument` within the QML TextEdit object but I am concerned with the warning as provided within the documentation.

Is there any safe way of editing the `QTextDocument`? Such as with signals / slots or something? The fact that I can't edit the `QTextDocument` without risk of crashing seems like a rather large limitation within the design of QML, no? That it can only be modified from the UI itself?

Am I missing something?

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73833570/17726418) helps

Comment: @MihoubAbderrahmeneRayene Unfortunately not, as its quite a similar question. The SyntaxHighlighting is also a read only process if I understood correctly, so no direct changes to the underling QTextDocument are made.

Comment: @Adriano I didn't understand your syntax highlighting comment. I wanted to state that you can get the QSyntaxHighlighter working with the QML TextEdit component.

Comment: @StephenQuan I agree with you the QSyntaxHighlighter can work with QML TextEdit component, but want I meant is that the QSyntaxHighlighter is only reading the state of the QTextDocument, it doesn't make changes to it directly and I'm looking to make changes to the QTextDocument that is owned by the QQuickTextDocument which is in turned owned the QML TextEdit component

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot change the internal state of the `QTextEdit`. Treat it as if it were `const`.

To change the text of the document, the `TextEdit` component itself provides methods, such as [`insert(int position, string text)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#insert-method) and [`string remove(int start, int end)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#remove-method).

Granted, this is much more limited than using a `QTextCursor`, but enough to make your collaborative text editor a possibility.

If you truly want control, you might want to implement your own QML Type. Then you will have full control over any internals.

Comment: This is the current implementation and I don't like it too much as I only see it as a work around. I would much prefer to keep the logic within C++ as the entirety of the collaborative text mechanisms are within C++. Implementing my own QML type was something I was attempting to avoid but it seems its now more on the cards.

Comment: @Adriano I understand that "no, can't do it" answers are not very satisfying, but in this case that's really all there is to it. The documentation is clear.